# Ticker-style getting cut in Mobile View

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The requirement is to sow the information continuously hence opted for a ticker style.

Now I am using an [ticker-style.css] along with [jquery.ticker.js]

It works fine in a Full Screen however while browsing in a Mobile/Tabler - the text is getting cut (see below screenshot) - I tried to play around the width however the rendering was not as expected.

Can you help here.

Thanks in advance.

```js
/*
    jQuery News Ticker is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, version 2 of the License.
 
    jQuery News Ticker is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with jQuery News Ticker.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
(function($){  
    $.fn.ticker = function(options) { 
        // Extend our default options with those provided.
        // Note that the first arg to extend is an empty object -
        // this is to keep from overriding our "defaults" object.
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ticker.defaults, options); 

        // check that the passed element is actually in the DOM
        if ($(this).length == 0) {
            if (window.console && window.console.log) {
                window.console.log('Element does not exist in DOM!');
            }
            else {
                alert('Element does not exist in DOM!');        
            }
            return false;
        }
        
        /* Get the id of the UL to get our news content from */
        var newsID = '#' + $(this).attr('id');

        /* Get the tag type - we will check this later to makde sure it is a UL tag */
        var tagType = $(this).get(0).tagName;   

        return this.each(function() { 
            // get a unique id for this ticker
            var uniqID = getUniqID();
            
            /* Internal vars */
            var settings = {                
                position: 0,
                time: 0,
                distance: 0,
                newsArr: {},
                play: true,
                paused: false,
                contentLoaded: false,
                dom: {
                    contentID: '#ticker-content-' + uniqID,
                    titleID: '#ticker-title-' + uniqID,
                    titleElem: '#ticker-title-' + uniqID + ' SPAN',
                    tickerID : '#ticker-' + uniqID,
                    wrapperID: '#ticker-wrapper-' + uniqID,
                    revealID: '#ticker-swipe-' + uniqID,
                    revealElem: '#ticker-swipe-' + uniqID + ' SPAN',
                    controlsID: '#ticker-controls-' + uniqID,
                    prevID: '#prev-' + uniqID,
                    nextID: '#next-' + uniqID,
                    playPauseID: '#play-pause-' + uniqID
                }
            };

            // if we are not using a UL, display an error message and stop any further execution
            if (tagType != 'UL' && tagType != 'OL' && opts.htmlFeed === true) {
                debugError('Cannot use <' + tagType.toLowerCase() + '> type of element for this plugin - must of type <ul> or <ol>');
                return false;
            }

            // set the ticker direction
            opts.direction == 'rtl' ? opts.direction = 'right' : opts.direction = 'left';
            
            // lets go...
            initialisePage();
            /* Function to get the size of an Object*/
            function countSize(obj) {
                var size = 0, key;
                for (key in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
                }
                return size;
            };

            function getUniqID() {
                var newDate = new Date;
                return newDate.getTime();           
            }
            
            /* Function for handling debug and error messages */ 
            function debugError(obj) {
                if (opts.debugMode) {
                    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
                        window.console.log(obj);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(obj);         
                    }
                }
            }

            /* Function to setup the page */
            function initialisePage() {
                // process the content for this ticker
                processContent();
                
                // add our HTML structure for the ticker to the DOM
                $(newsID).wrap('<div id="' + settings.dom.wrapperID.replace('#', '') + '"></div>');
                
                // remove any current content inside this ticker
                $(settings.dom.wrapperID).children().remove();
                
                $(settings.dom.wrapperID).append('<div id="' + settings.dom.tickerID.replace('#', '') + '" class="ticker"><div id="' + settings.dom.titleID.replace('#', '') + '" class="ticker-title"><span><!-- --></span></div><p id="' + settings.dom.contentID.replace('#', '') + '" class="ticker-content"></p><div id="' + settings.dom.revealID.replace('#', '') + '" class="ticker-swipe"><span><!-- --></span></div></div>');
                $(settings.dom.wrapperID).removeClass('no-js').addClass('ticker-wrapper has-js ' + opts.direction);
                // hide the ticker
                $(settings.dom.tickerElem + ',' + settings.dom.contentID).hide();
                // add the controls to the DOM if required
                if (opts.controls) {
                    // add related events - set functions to run on given event
                    $(settings.dom.controlsID).on('click mouseover mousedown mouseout mouseup', function (e) {
                        var button = e.target.id;
                        if (e.type == 'click') {    
                            switch (button) {
                                case settings.dom.prevID.replace('#', ''):
                                    // show previous item
                                    settings.paused = true;
                                    $(settings.dom.playPauseID).addClass('paused');
                                    manualChangeContent('prev');
                                    break;
                                case settings.dom.nextID.replace('#', ''):
                                    // show next item
                                    settings.paused = true;
                                    $(settings.dom.playPauseID).addClass('paused');
                                    manualChangeContent('next');
                                    break;
                                case settings.dom.playPauseID.replace('#', ''):
                                    // play or pause the ticker
                                    if (settings.play == true) {
                                        settings.paused = true;
                                        $(settings.dom.playPauseID).addClass('paused');
                                        pauseTicker();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        settings.paused = false;
                                        $(settings.dom.playPauseID).removeClass('paused');
                                        restartTicker();
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }   
                        }
                        else if (e.type == 'mouseover' && $('#' + button).hasClass('controls')) {
                            $('#' + button).addClass('over');
                        }
                        else if (e.type == 'mousedown' && $('#' + button).hasClass('controls')) {
                            $('#' + button).addClass('down');
                        }
                        else if (e.type == 'mouseup' && $('#' + button).hasClass('controls')) {
                            $('#' + button).removeClass('down');
                        }
                        else if (e.type == 'mouseout' && $('#' + button).hasClass('controls')) {
                            $('#' + button).removeClass('over');
                        }
                    });
                    // add controls HTML to DOM
                    $(settings.dom.wrapperID).append('<ul id="' + settings.dom.controlsID.replace('#', '') + '" class="ticker-controls"><li id="' + settings.dom.playPauseID.replace('#', '') + '" class="jnt-play-pause controls"><a href=""><!-- --></a></li><li id="' + settings.dom.prevID.replace('#', '') + '" class="jnt-prev controls"><a href=""><!-- --></a></li><li id="' + settings.dom.nextID.replace('#', '') + '" class="jnt-next controls"><a href=""><!-- --></a></li></ul>');
                }
                if (opts.displayType != 'fade') {
                    // add mouse over on the content
                    $(settings.dom.contentID).mouseover(function () {
                        if (settings.paused == false) {
                            pauseTicker();
                        }
                    }).mouseout(function () {
                        if (settings.paused == false) {
                            restartTicker();
                        }
                    });
                }
                // we may have to wait for the ajax call to finish here
                if (!opts.ajaxFeed) {
                    setupContentAndTriggerDisplay();
                }
            }

            /* Start to process the content for this ticker */
            function processContent() {
                // check to see if we need to load content
                if (settings.contentLoaded == false) {
                    // construct content
                    if (opts.ajaxFeed) {
                        if (opts.feedType == 'xml') {                           
                            $.ajax({
                                url: opts.feedUrl,
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: opts.feedType,
                                async: true,
                                success: function(data){
                                    count = 0;  
                                    // get the 'root' node
                                    for (var a = 0; a < data.childNodes.length; a++) {
                                        if (data.childNodes[a].nodeName == 'rss') {
                                            xmlContent = data.childNodes[a];
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // find the channel node
                                    for (var i = 0; i < xmlContent.childNodes.length; i++) {
                                        if (xmlContent.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'channel') {
                                            xmlChannel = xmlContent.childNodes[i];
                                        }       
                                    }
                                    // for each item create a link and add the article title as the link text
                                    for (var x = 0; x < xmlChannel.childNodes.length; x++) {
                                        if (xmlChannel.childNodes[x].nodeName == 'item') {
                                            xmlItems = xmlChannel.childNodes[x];
                                            var title, link = false;
                                            for (var y = 0; y < xmlItems.childNodes.length; y++) {
                                                if (xmlItems.childNodes[y].nodeName == 'title') {                                                       
                                                    title = xmlItems.childNodes[y].lastChild.nodeValue;
                                                }
                                                else if (xmlItems.childNodes[y].nodeName == 'link') {                                                   
                                                    link = xmlItems.childNodes[y].lastChild.nodeValue; 
                                                }
                                                if ((title !== false && title != '') && link !== false) {
                                                    settings.newsArr['item-' + count] = { type: opts.titleText, content: '<a href="' + link + '">' + title + '</a>' };                                                  count++;                                                    title = false;                                                  link = false;
                                                }
                                            }   
                                        }       
                                    }           
                                    // quick check here to see if we actually have any content - log error if not
                                    if (countSize(settings.newsArr < 1)) {
                                        debugError('Couldn\'t find any content from the XML feed for the ticker to use!');
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    settings.contentLoaded = true;
                                    setupContentAndTriggerDisplay();
                                }
                            });                         
                        }
                        else {
                            debugError('Code Me!'); 
                        }                       
                    }
                    else if (opts.htmlFeed) { 
                        if($(newsID + ' LI').length > 0) {
                            $(newsID + ' LI').each(function (i) {
                                // maybe this could be one whole object and not an array of objects?
                                settings.newsArr['item-' + i] = { type: opts.titleText, content: $(this).html()};
                            });     
                        }   
                        else {
                            debugError('Couldn\'t find HTML any content for the ticker to use!');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        debugError('The ticker is set to not use any types of content! Check the settings for the ticker.');
                        return false;
                    }                   
                }           
            }

            function setupContentAndTriggerDisplay() {

                settings.contentLoaded = true;

                // update the ticker content with the correct item
                // insert news content into DOM
                $(settings.dom.titleElem).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].type);
                $(settings.dom.contentID).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].content);

                // set the next content item to be used - loop round if we are at the end of the content
                if (settings.position == (countSize(settings.newsArr) -1)) {
                    settings.position = 0;
                }
                else {      
                    settings.position++;
                }           

                // get the values of content and set the time of the reveal (so all reveals have the same speed regardless of content size)
                distance = $(settings.dom.contentID).width();
                time = distance / opts.speed;

                // start the ticker animation                       
                revealContent();        
            }

            // slide back cover or fade in content
            function revealContent() {
                $(settings.dom.contentID).css('opacity', '1');
                if(settings.play) { 
                    // get the width of the title element to offset the content and reveal  
                    var offset = $(settings.dom.titleID).width() + 20;
    
                    $(settings.dom.revealID).css(opts.direction, offset + 'px');
                    // show the reveal element and start the animation
                    if (opts.displayType == 'fade') {
                        // fade in effect ticker
                        $(settings.dom.revealID).hide(0, function () {
                            $(settings.dom.contentID).css(opts.direction, offset + 'px').fadeIn(opts.fadeInSpeed, postReveal);
                        });                     
                    }
                    else if (opts.displayType == 'scroll') {
                        // to code
                    }
                    else {
                        // default bbc scroll effect
                        $(settings.dom.revealElem).show(0, function () {
                            $(settings.dom.contentID).css(opts.direction, offset + 'px').show();
                            // set our animation direction
                            animationAction = opts.direction == 'right' ? { marginRight: distance + 'px'} : { marginLeft: distance + 'px' };
                            $(settings.dom.revealID).css('margin-' + opts.direction, '0px').delay(20).animate(animationAction, time, 'linear', postReveal);
                        });     
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return false;                   
                }
            };

            // here we hide the current content and reset the ticker elements to a default state ready for the next ticker item
            function postReveal() {             
                if(settings.play) {     
                    // we have to separately fade the content out here to get around an IE bug - needs further investigation
                    $(settings.dom.contentID).delay(opts.pauseOnItems).fadeOut(opts.fadeOutSpeed);
                    // deal with the rest of the content, prepare the DOM and trigger the next ticker
                    if (opts.displayType == 'fade') {
                        $(settings.dom.contentID).fadeOut(opts.fadeOutSpeed, function () {
                            $(settings.dom.wrapperID)
                                .find(settings.dom.revealElem + ',' + settings.dom.contentID)
                                    .hide()
                                .end().find(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID)
                                    .show()
                                .end().find(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID)
                                    .removeAttr('style');                               
                            setupContentAndTriggerDisplay();                        
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $(settings.dom.revealID).hide(0, function () {
                            $(settings.dom.contentID).fadeOut(opts.fadeOutSpeed, function () {
                                $(settings.dom.wrapperID)
                                    .find(settings.dom.revealElem + ',' + settings.dom.contentID)
                                        .hide()
                                    .end().find(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID)
                                        .show()
                                    .end().find(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID)
                                        .removeAttr('style');                               
                                setupContentAndTriggerDisplay();                        
                            });
                        }); 
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $(settings.dom.revealElem).hide();
                }
            }

            // pause ticker
            function pauseTicker() {                
                settings.play = false;
                // stop animation and show content - must pass "true, true" to the stop function, or we can get some funky behaviour
                $(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID + ',' + settings.dom.titleID + ',' + settings.dom.titleElem + ',' + settings.dom.revealElem + ',' + settings.dom.contentID).stop(true, true);
                $(settings.dom.revealID + ',' + settings.dom.revealElem).hide();
                $(settings.dom.wrapperID)
                    .find(settings.dom.titleID + ',' + settings.dom.titleElem).show()
                        .end().find(settings.dom.contentID).show();
            }

            // play ticker
            function restartTicker() {              
                settings.play = true;
                settings.paused = false;
                // start the ticker again
                postReveal();   
            }

            // change the content on user input
            function manualChangeContent(direction) {
                pauseTicker();
                switch (direction) {
                    case 'prev':
                        if (settings.position == 0) {
                            settings.position = countSize(settings.newsArr) -2;
                        }
                        else if (settings.position == 1) {
                            settings.position = countSize(settings.newsArr) -1;
                        }
                        else {
                            settings.position = settings.position - 2;
                        }
                        $(settings.dom.titleElem).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].type);
                        $(settings.dom.contentID).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].content);                      
                        break;
                    case 'next':
                        $(settings.dom.titleElem).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].type);
                        $(settings.dom.contentID).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].content);
                        break;
                }
                // set the next content item to be used - loop round if we are at the end of the content
                if (settings.position == (countSize(settings.newsArr) -1)) {
                    settings.position = 0;
                }
                else {      
                    settings.position++;
                }   
            }
        });  
    };  

    // plugin defaults - added as a property on our plugin function
    $.fn.ticker.defaults = {
        speed: 0.10,            
        ajaxFeed: false,
        feedUrl: '',
        feedType: 'xml',
        displayType: 'reveal',
        htmlFeed: true,
        debugMode: true,
        controls: true,
        titleText: '',  
        direction: 'ltr',   
        pauseOnItems: 3000,
        fadeInSpeed: 600,
        fadeOutSpeed: 300
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* Ticker Styling */
.ticker-wrapper.has-js {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 780px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color:inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
.ticker {
    width: 710px;
    height: 23px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    @media #{$xs}{
        width: 200px;
    }
}
.ticker-title {
padding-top: 9px;
color: #990000;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #fff;
text-transform: capitalize;
}
.ticker-content {
    margin: 0px;
    /* padding-top: 9px; */
    position: absolute;
    color: #506172;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.ticker-content:focus {
 none;
}
.ticker-content a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #1F527B;
}
.ticker-content a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #0D3059;
}
.ticker-swipe {
padding-top: 9px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
background-color: #fff;
display: block;
width: 800px;
height: 23px;
}
.ticker-swipe span {
margin-left: 1px;
background-color: #fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #1F527B;
height: 12px;
width: 7px;
display: block;
}
.ticker-controls {
padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
}
.ticker-controls li {
padding: 0px;
margin-left: 5px;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display: block;
}

.ticker-controls li.jnt-play-pause {
background-image: url('../images/controls.png');
background-position: 32px 16px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-play-pause.over {
background-position: 32px 32px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-play-pause.down {
background-position: 32px 0px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-play-pause.paused {
background-image: url('../images/controls.png');
background-position: 48px 16px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-play-pause.paused.over {
background-position: 48px 32px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-play-pause.paused.down {
background-position: 48px 0px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-prev {
background-image: url('../images/controls.png');
background-position: 0px 16px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-prev.over {
background-position: 0px 32px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-prev.down {
background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-next {
background-image: url('../images/controls.png');
background-position: 16px 16px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-next.over {
background-position: 16px 32px;
}
.ticker-controls li.jnt-next.down {
background-position: 16px 0px;
}
.js-hidden {
display: none;
}
.no-js-news {
padding: 10px 0px 0px 45px;
color: #fff;
}
.left .ticker-swipe {
/*left: 80px;*/
}
.left .ticker-controls, .left .ticker-content, .left .ticker-title, .left .ticker {
float: left;
}
.left .ticker-controls {
padding-left: 6px;
}
.right .ticker-swipe {
/*right: 80px;*/
}
.right .ticker-controls, .right .ticker-content, .right .ticker-title, .right .ticker {
float: right;
}
.right .ticker-controls {
padding-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Trending now</strong>
                            <!-- <p>Rem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p> -->
                            <div class="trending-animated">
                                <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">
                                    <li class="news-item">Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                                    <li class="news-item">Spondon IT sit amet, consectetur.......</li>
                                    <li class="news-item">Rem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please see how to create a [MRE] and update your question to include only the code that is needed to recreate the problem, so we can see what is happening more clearly and be able to help.

Comment: To simplify, I have uploaded the Html, Css & JS code to a temporary bin: https://filebin.net/37i7lsl5y38sqfa7/aznews.zip?t=t208yhsn

Comment: here is the link to the updated code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/wsgzkLf6/

Comment: Your fiddle still isn't showing the issue - there is no ticker running in it at all?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have re-updated the links and checked in 2 differents browsers - can you check once more and confirm plz: https://jsfiddle.net/L75ysko1/

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in Chrome https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMfQg.png

Comment: @FluffyKittenThe link (mark in red) is not the right one: https://imgur.com/a/WRfOB7D

Requesting you to check with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L75ysko1/

You should see a text running like this: https://imgur.com/a/aVdKTMj

Comment: @FluffyKittentry with this one https://jsfiddle.net/L75ysko1/

Comment: That is still not working. FYI it has this `?t=zynndr3o"` on the filebin links now. I don't really know what to tell you, it just isn't working for me. Someone else might be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten: sorry for that - it seems that the files in filebin.net aren't loading properly - I have added the JS dependencies directly in jsfiddle - can you check with this: https://jsfiddle.net/umadLg6o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting fixed widths for ticker elements.The ticker container has a width of 720px no matter what size the screen, and on screens < 767px the container for the scrolling text is just 230px.

Either change the CSS if it is your own, or if not you can add these rules *after* the Ticker CSS in included:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .ticker-wrapper.has-js,
  .ticker,
  .trending-tittle .ticker {
        width: 100%!important;
  }
}
```

This sets them to use the full width of the screen.

Comment: the last question would be: on a mobile view - when the text is too long so it doesn't fit it completely - is there any way to Line Break it automatically ?

Comment: @fmourtaza It looks like the ticker script doesn't work that way, the way it is set up here anyway. You could check if there is an option or setting to change this functionality.